# Set a printer for app using a Dialog

Tags: c#, wpf

My application prints without showing the PrintDialog (and it need to do so) but I'd like to be able to set to which printer it should print so I added an appsetting in the app.config where it stores the printer name. what I want is a dialog where it shows all printer and the user should be able to choose a printer and it will save in the app.config (I could actually do it from the PrintDialog and get the chosen printer but  the button says Print and I don't want to confuse the User...) 
Thanks
**edit**
@methodMan Asked  for code so I added My code

```
 System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog ps = new  System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
      //set the selected printer in the dialog to the current printer 
       ps.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.ContinuesLabelPrinter;
       var result =  ps.ShowDialog();
        if(result ==  System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.ContinuesLabelPrinter = ps.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        }
```

Comment: so how do you expect anyone to help you without seeing your existing code.. have you looked at how to ask a question ? also in regards to what you are wanting ..what have you done thus far on your own.. any research..?

Comment: I would educate the users and use PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();  Printing through the dialog is so common that everyone should know how to use it.

Comment: @waltmagic the printing  has to go seamlessly  like quick print but the user has to be able to set a printer (not by setting the default printer to that printer) what i meant by confusing the user is that the printDialog header says print so hell think that he printing when he's really not

Comment: @MethodMan Iv'e edited my question added my code

Comment: here is the `PrintDialog Class` [MSDN PrintDialog Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) there is a working example at the bottom of the page.. also please tell us if you have debugged the code by stepping through line by line

Comment: @mehodman I hope that you read thru my question before voting it down

Comment: @Joe B I know what you are wanting to do.  I feel your pain btw because I get these types of requests all the time where I work.  To do what you want there are two ways that I can think of. 1st way would be to override the printDialog.ShowDialog() method and the 2nd way would be to edit the config file and add all the printer names. Then  the user can select which printer to print to using a custom made form.  It might be more feasible to educate the users and limit the number of installed printers to only the one's needed to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is something that will work for you I think...Create a windows Form with a listbox and two buttons.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(printer);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

In your code do this:

```
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    if(form2.Show() ==  System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.ContinuesLabelPrinter = form2.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    form2.Dispose();  // <-- this might not be necessary
```

You will need to make the listBox1 public for this to work.